# Javascript Looping over array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

In my project I have an image gallery and a canvas to display the image clicked from gallery.  For many images, I am drawing rectangles and have the coordinates of the rectangles stored in MySQL.  Using JavaScript and PHP, whenever the image from the gallery is clicked, based on the image name I am fetching the rectangle coordinates from MySQL.

The codes to fetch the values from MySQL as an array to JavaScript is as follows:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$clickedImg = $_POST['clickedImg'];
$query = mysql_query("select x,y,w,h from annotations where imagename = '$clickedImg'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
 print_r($row);
}
?>
```

Instead of print_r when I tried echo, it just returns a blank array.
The fetched array when printed on console looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [x] => 369
    [y] => 327
    [w] => 147
    [h] => 112
)
Array
(
    [x] => 228
    [y] => 329
    [w] => 129
    [h] => 106
)
```

My original script to draw rectangles at fixed locations is as follows:

```
function draw(canvas, event){
    ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="#ff0000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect (250*Math.random()+1, 220*Math.random()+1, 40, 30);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    // Save canvas
    saveCanvas(canvas);
}
```

This just prints rectanges at random locations.  I want to use the values in the above mentioned array in the place of `ctx.fillRect`.

I tried the following:

```
function draw(canvas, event){
    ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="#ff0000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var i=0; i<=newrects.length;i++) {
      var r = newrects[i];
      alert(r);
      ctx.fillRect (r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    // Save canvas
    saveCanvas(canvas);
}
```

I essentially want to draw the rectangles using the values in the Array.  But the current for loop inside draw function is not reading the values.  Hence, I am not sure if the format in which I receive the values from PHP is correct or not.

How can use the values from the array in the for loop of my draw function.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) that has been [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) from PHP. You should select a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You should encode your array into `json` using `$arr = json_encode($arr)` and pass it to the `js` function and parse it into `var arr = JSON.parse(<?php echo $arr; ?>)` and iterate this array in `js`

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov — JSON is not an encryption algorithm!

Comment: @Quentin: thanks a lot, it was just a typo! )))